# Render HTML in Server side with React and NExt Js

Tags: reactjs, fetch, next.js, server-side-rendering

Am using Next Js and React Server side rendering for my allpication to render on server side.

I My Application i have a 
api calls to make to load data to HTML which needs ot be updated in HTML.

componentDidMount will not work as i dont ship my js files to client side.

i have tried getInitialProps as well still no luck any suggestions would be of great help.

```js
//From index.js i Navigate to Redirection.tsk in index.js page
//redirection.ts

import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import Redirection from '../data';
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server"
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';


export default (_req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
  const data :_req.headers.referer ;
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Redirection data={data} />);
  res.send(`
  <!DOCTYPE html />
  <html>
  <head>
      ${helmet.meta.toString()}
      ${helmet.title.toString()}
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="app">${html}</div>
  </body>
  <script>window.__INITIAL__DATA__ = ${JSON.stringify({ data })}</script>
  </html>
    `);
}

//----
//Data.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import {IState,IProps} from '../domain/reactelements'



class Redirection extends React.Component {
  state: IState;
  props:IProps;
  constructor(data:IProps) {
    super(data);
    this.props={data:data}
    this.state = { message: '' };
    
  }
  static async getInitialProps(){
    console.log('Please work');
 const value =  calls External api to get data;
  }
  Headers = (title:string) => {
    return (
      <Helmet>
        <title>{title}</title>
      </Helmet>
    );
  };
  call api =  {
    try {
      const doRequest = 
   //calling API from here
      const response = await doRequest;
      this.handleResponse(response.json());
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ message: ERROR });
      return false;
    }
  };

  handleResponse(response:string){
    if (response.Status == 'error') {
      this.setState({ message: 'rejected' + response.Id });
    }
    else { 
        if (doRequest.ok) {
        const status = api call
        if (status && response.Status == 'auth') {
          this.setState({ message: 'success'});
        }
        else if(status && response.Status == 'cancelled')
        {
          this.setState({ message: 'error' + response.Id});
        }
        else {
          this.setState({ message: 'default' + response.Id});
        }
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    console.log('in Payment Info render');
    return (
      <div className="loader-center">
        {this.state.message && (
          <React.Fragment>
            {this.Headers('Processing data...')}
            <div className="status-text">{this.state.message}</div>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        {!this.state.message && (
          <React.Fragment>
            {this.Headers('Processing data...')}
            <div className="loader" />
            <div className="loader-text">Please wait while processing...</div>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Redirection;
```

Thanks
Arjun.M

Comment: This is similar to the question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421060/reactjs-server-side-rendering-and-componentdidmount-method

Comment: @400_bad_request
i  have checked the above link but  it is expecting me to expose my index.js file with
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppRoutes from './components/AppRoutes';

window.onload = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<AppRoutes/>, document.getElementById('main'));
};

there should be  some way to resolve my issue .